# Como puedo detectar click derecho en un gameObject de Unity

Tags: c#, unity, motor-de-juego

estoy aprendiendo a usar Unity y me gustaría saber si hay alguna alternativa de OnMouseDown y OnMouseUp para click derecho (y click central). O sea lo que busco es que cuando se haga click derecho en ese objeto lo detecte pero que hasta que no se deje de pulsar no surja efecto. Digamos que lo que sucede con un botón. El juego es en 2D. He probado la función OnMouseOver pero no obtengo el resultado que quiero. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alejandro!

Si he entendido bien, quizás podrías probar a utilizar `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)` para detectar cuando se ha pulsado el click izquierdo (o `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2)` para el botón central), y `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1)` para detectar cuando se ha soltado.

Si quieres usar esto para detectar si estás tocando un objeto, deberías crear un script que usando Raycasting básico te diga si estás interactuando con el objeto. Es sencillo, lanzas un raycast hacia la dirección donde clickes, y así sabes si has encontrado el objeto (puedes usar tags, por ejemplo, para identificar el objeto).

Se puede encontrar info sobre esto fácilmente googleando. Coméntame si no consigues encontrarlo, un saludo!